# assign values to all columns in 2D array in one statement

Tags: verilog

I would like to assign value to an array. The array is 2 dimensional it has 16 rows and 16 col. Each element is 2 bits wide.

I would like to initialize each row of an array like so:

Initialize the 4th row of the array, then each value should be stored in respective column,  so 0 will be in 15th col, 2 will be in 12th col, etc. I do not want to store values column by column. I've tried implementing it below but my code is erroring.

```
module test2;

    reg [1:0] mem [15:0][15:0];

    wire [1:0] icon;

    assign icon = mem[4][4];

    mem[4][15:0] = 16'h0002000000000000;

    $strobe("%b", icon);

endmodule;
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electrical engineering

Comment: it is about verilog which you use in electrical engineering.

Comment: @user3551094 It would be advisable to add the error that the code is giving you.

Answer (score 1):

`mem[4][15:0] = 16'h0002000000000000;` and `$strobe("%b", icon);` need to be in an `assign` statement, `initial` block, or `always` block.

`mem` is also delcared incorrectly if you want to assign as `mem[4][15:0]`. it should be declared as double packed, single unpacked multi-dimensional arrays: `reg  [15:0][1:0] mem [15:0];`

The following compiles and runs without errors:

```
module test2;
    reg  [15:0][1:0] mem [15:0];
    wire [1:0] icon;
    assign icon = mem[4][4];

    initial begin
        mem[4][15:0] = 16'h0002000000000000;
        $strobe("%b", icon);
    end
endmodule;
```